# Rebol 3 functions MODIFIED? and EXISTS? don't work on URL type

Tags: rebol, rebol3

Do any of the REBOL 3 gurus here know why the `modified?`, `exists?` and `size?` functions fail on R3 when targeting a URL?

These functions work fine on local files.

I am very familiar with R2, but R3 behavior seems strange at times. I am using stock code compiled from the Dec 12, 2012 open source release, and am running on Windows 7.

Comment: r3 (ren-c) branch now has these working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mainly, support for those functions is not yet implemented for most URL schemes (see for example, issue [#467](http://issue.cc/r3/467) for HTTP, or [#1826](http://issue.cc/r3/1826) for DNS).

All three mentioned functions use QUERY as the underlying action to obtain the information needed. So it's a matter of the implementation for a particular URL scheme also properly implementing full QUERY support.

Comment: Thanks, @earl. Looks like porting old code from R2 to R3 is going to take a little longer than I expected.